# Looping over attributes of model instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an instance `people = Person.all` and would like to loop over it to get the first_name attribute for each person. I have tried the following:

```
people.each do |first_name|
  puts #{first_name}
end
```

How to construct the loop as to output all of the First Names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redo your code so it looks like this:

```
people.each do |person|
  puts person.first_name
end
```

In this code, `person` is the name of the individual object you are looping over. So calling `person.first_name` will call the first_name of that individual.

Answer (score 0):

```
people = Person.all
puts people.map(&:name).join(' ')
```

Comment: You are creating two unnecessary arrays.  Doesn't it make more sense to just loop through `people`, printing their first names?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What if, instead of looping, we fetch all the first names in one query?

```
puts Person.pluck(:first_name).join("\n")
```

If it needs to be an array of people, this would work too

```
puts people.map(&:first_name).join("\n")
```